# Xibs in Resource bundle only compiled for small screens

Tags: ios, xcode5

I've created a resource bundle with images and xibs for a cocoa pod. The xibs seems to be compiled only for 3.5" displays. So when running on a 4" screen it looks weird.

Is there some compiler flag I should provide in build settings? How is this usually solved?

Comment: What do you mean with `it looks weird` ? Could you add a picture please ?

Comment: Ah. It's letter boxed, the xib is the correct size for a 3.5" screen, and then black is added on top and bottom. Picture coming shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a default splashscreen for iPhone 5 in your resources with name :

`Default-568h@2x.png`

and the size of this splashscreen is : 640*1136

**Filename Dimensions**

[image]

**[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)**

Comment: I had one in a asset catalog. But It started working when I removed the asset catalog. Many thanks!